# Question regarding the basis, eigenvectors, and diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

There's a portion of  a problem assigned to me of which I do not understand the answer. The problem is as follows: "Find a basis $B$ for $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that the matrix $A$ relative to $B$ is diagonal."

Now beforehand we found that the diagonal vector of A was $D=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$ where the diagonal entries were the eigenvalues of A. My professor claimed the the basis B is the diagonal D. I can't seem to understand why that is. Can anyone explain?

Edit: Included more information
This was the standard matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & 3 & 1 \\
-3 & 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: It'd be helpful if you gave us the matrix $A$.

Comment: Are you sure your professor claimed this? When we write $A=PDP^{-1}$, the diagonal entries of the diagonal matrix $D$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ and the columns of $P$ are the eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: @EuYu okay I added A.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick I'm pretty sure that is what he said.

Comment: I think the basis you want is the columns of $P$, or the eigenvectors of $A$. I agree with Brian that the professor shouldn't have said that.

Comment: @PaulHurst I seriously doubt that the professor said this. It's much more likely that OP either misheard or is misremembering whatever the professor did say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would do you well to review diagonalization, so let's walk through this example. I'm assuming you have a basic knowledge of matrix manipulations and basic facts from linear algebra.

We would like to diagonalize the matrix
$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & -1\\ 1 & 3 & 1 \\ -3 & 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
To do so, we need to compute the eigenvalues of $A$ and find bases for the eigenspaces of $A$. The eigenvalues are precisely the roots of the characteristic polynomial of $A$. In this case the characteristic polynomial is
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{char}{char}\char_A(\lambda)
=\det(A-\lambda\cdot I)=-(\lambda+2)(\lambda-2)(\lambda-3)
$$
The eigenvalues of $A$ are thus
\begin{align*}
\lambda_1 &= -2 & \lambda_2 &= 2 & \lambda_3 &=3
\end{align*}
and the *algebraic multiplicity* of each eigenvalue is one.

Now, for each eigenvalue $\lambda_k$, let $E_{\lambda_k}$ be the associated *eigenspace*
$$
E_{\lambda_k}=\{\mathsf v\in\Bbb R^3:A\mathsf v=\lambda_k \mathsf v\}=\DeclareMathOperator{Null}{Null}\Null(A-\lambda_k\cdot I)
$$
In our case, we have
\begin{align*}
E_{\lambda_1} &= \Null\begin{bmatrix}3&-1&-1\\  1&5&1\\  -3&1&1\end{bmatrix} &
E_{\lambda_2} &= \Null\begin{bmatrix}-1&-1&-1\\  1&1&1\\  -3&1&-3\end{bmatrix} &
E_{\lambda_3} &= \Null\begin{bmatrix}-2&-1&-1\\  1&0&1\\  -3&1&-4\end{bmatrix}  \\
&\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}=\Span\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\4\end{bmatrix}\right\} &&
=\Span\left\{\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}\right\} 
&&
=\Span\left\{\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}\right\} 
\end{align*}
This gives bases for each eigenspace (I'm skipping details here. If you don't understand what I have written, I strongly encourage you to review how to find bases for nullspaces).

Finally, since $A$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix and we have $3$ linearly independent eigenvalues of $A$, we know that $A$ is diagonalizable. It's diagonalization is
$$
A=PDP^{-1}
$$
where 
\begin{align*}
D &= \begin{bmatrix}-2&0&-\\ 0& 2&0\\ 0&0&3\end{bmatrix} &
P &= \begin{bmatrix}1&-1&-1\\ -1&0&1\\ 4&1&1\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Note that the diagonal entries of $D$ are exactly the eigenvalues of $A$ and that the columns of $P$ are exactly the associated eigenvectors of $A$.

In short, the basis $B$ for $\Bbb R^3$ such that the matrix of $A$ relative to $B$ is diagonal is 
$$
B=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\4\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}\right\}
$$